# Loading jars from Database and setting them in classpath

Tags: java, oop, web-applications, jar

I will store some jar files to database. When application server started I want to fetch jar files from database and set those jar files in classpath.

How can we achieve this?

Any help on this regard, really appreciated.

Regards,
Narendra

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on [fetching a blob from a database](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1325). Then just [save the byte array to a file](http://www.java-examples.com/write-byte-array-file-using-fileoutputstream) on the class path.